# Launch macvim in Mac terminal in current directory

Tags: mac, terminal, macvim

I know that I can open `macvim` in terminal using `open -a macvim`. The problem is it opens in the user home directory.

How can I open it so the directory is in the current directory?

Comment: ... Have you tried just using `macvim`?

Comment: can't run macvim from the commandline.

Comment: okay, so I opened it from the commandline with: /Applications/MacVim.app/Contents/MacOS/MacVim. It still opened in the home directory. I tried using the path but I don't thing the path of app contents can be searched.

Answer (score -1):

`open -a macvim` plus a period will open `macvim` in the current directory. Otherwise it will open in the main directory.